# Newsfeed implementation in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph with two kinds of nodes: User and Activity. Users may be friends with each other. I want to fetch the newsfeed of a user. Following is my query:

```
      MATCH (me:User) WHERE me.id = '#{opts[:user_id]}'
      MATCH (me)-[:FRIEND*0..1]->(user)-[:CREATE_ACTIVITY]->(activity)
      RETURN  activity.id AS id,
              activity.created_at AS created_at,
              activity.activity_type AS activity_type,
              {
                id: user.id,
                name: user.name,
                avatar_name: user.avatar_name
              } AS user

      ORDER BY activity.created_at
      LIMIT 10
```

However, this query is not efficient, since it seems not to apply indexes and will scan ALL data. In addition, after I added index on Activity:created_at, nothing changed.

Could anyone provide an efficient method to fetch newsfeed?

---

Update:

I am using Ruby gem.

I have index on id field of User and Activity, and also on created_at of Activity. I was expecting the ORDER BY will use the index on created_at, but it does not.

Comment: What are your indexes?

Comment: I also notice that you're interpolation is using `#{}`.  Are you using ruby?  If so, are you using the neo4j gem or something else?  The neo4j/neo4j-core gem would make writing the cypher nicer

Comment: The indexes are not used for ordering, could you share the profile of your query (from the neo4j-shell or localhost:7474/webadmin -> console) - prefix your query with the `profile ` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Re-writing the query a bit and using params:

```
MATCH (me:User)-[:FRIEND*0..1]->(user)
WHERE me.id = {user_id}
WITH user LIMIT 1000
MATCH user-[:CREATE_ACTIVITY]->(activity)
RETURN  activity.id AS id,
        activity.created_at AS created_at,
        activity.activity_type AS activity_type,
        {
          id: user.id,
          name: user.name,
          avatar_name: user.avatar_name
        } AS user

ORDER BY activity.created_at
LIMIT 10
```

Params can help speed things up, but I doubt that's the problem.  How many friends does the user have?  Is there an index on the `id` property on user?  What about `created_at`?  Also note that `WHERE me.id =` is NOT the same as `WHERE ID(me) =`.  The first checks the `id` property, the second checks the internal neo ID

Comment: Hello! Please see my update:) A user may have at most 1000 friends.

Comment: I think that'll do it

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the indexes you speak of (i.e. they show up in profile),

you can try to change the query to:

```
  MATCH (me:User) WHERE me.id = '#{opts[:user_id]}'
  MATCH (me)-[:FRIEND*0..1]->(user)
  WITh distinct user
  MATCH (user)-[:CREATE_ACTIVITY]->(activity)
  RETURN  activity.id AS id,
          activity.created_at AS created_at,
          activity.activity_type AS activity_type,
          {
            id: user.id,
            name: user.name,
            avatar_name: user.avatar_name
          } AS user

  ORDER BY activity.created_at
  LIMIT 10
```